# Resign IPA to make it ad-hoc deploy able

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a bash script which resigns IPAs. But I want to edit it in a way such that the IPA resigned by it should be ad-hoc distributable. I've a developer cert n profile which when used in iOS app signer will make the IPA ad hoc. No matter what I do I just am NOT able to install that resigned ipa using my script with the correct plist. I enter the plist parameters correctly. I just need to know what should be be added in my script to make the resigned IPA ad hoc distributable. Please do help out. Thanks.

Comment: try this [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/)

Comment: Ma'am my script lets signs DITO like cydia impactor. Any ++apps I sign can be installed n they work fine. Fast lane doesn't. :(